# Escrever em arquivo.txt

Tags: java, android

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que preciso gravar dados no banco e ir salvando estes mesmos dados em um `arquivo.txt` na memória do dispositivo.
A parte do banco está ok, agora na parte do arquivo não encontrei ainda nenhuma documentação exemplificando. Se puderem me passar o link de alguma documentação especifica ou alguém demonstrar como implementar, fico muito agradecido.

Obs. A cada nova inserção, preciso concatenar o valor novo ao valor antigo criando assim uma lista de conteúdo no `arquivo.txt`. Ex:

> dado1;valores
>
> dado2;valores
>
> dado3;valores

Comment: Se vc vai salvar pares de chave-valor porque não usa sharedPreferences?

Comment: Qual o motivo de gravar em um txt?

Comment: Na realidade os valores são só um exemplo, preciso salvar muito mais informação... Este arquivo texto que preciso gerar também será uma especie de "Backup das informações", pois em um procedimento posterior o banco vai receber um delete, entretanto este arquivo texto tem que ficar salvo. O arquivo texto também servirá de "log" das informações. Como se fosse uma redundância da informação. Caso o SQLite falhe, tem vários motivos...

Answer (score 3):

Primeiramente você tem que dar permissão de leitura e escrita no seu `AndroidManifest.xml`. Veja:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Lembrando que deve observar e partir do Android 6.0 (nível de API 23), os usuários concedem permissões a aplicativos enquanto eles estão em execução, não quando eles são instalados. Veja mais detalhes sobre [solicitação de permissões em tempo de execução](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html?hl=pt-br).

> Essa abordagem otimiza o processo de instalação de aplicativos, pois o
>   usuário não precisa conceder permissões ao instalar ou atualizar o
>   aplicativo. Ela também confere ao usuário mais controle sobre os
>   recursos do aplicativo.

### Mão na massa

Depois de feito isso, você pode criar um método passando como parâmetro o contexto, o nome do arquivo e o conteúdo do arquivo, para gravação. Veja como ficaria:

```
public void gerarArquivo(Context context, String sFileName, String sBody) {
    try {
        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Notes");
        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdirs();
        }
        File gpxfile = new File(root, sFileName);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
        writer.append(sBody);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        //aqui você exibe na tela uma mensagem que o arquivo foi salvo
        Toast.makeText(context, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Para leitura do conteúdo do arquivo, podes criar um método passando como parâmetro o nome do arquivo no qual seu retorno será uma `String`. Veja como ficaria:

```
public static String lerArquivo(String rFilename) {

    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();    
    File file = new File(sdcard, rFilename);    
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
            text.append('\n');
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // exibir erro caso não funcione
    }

    return text.toString();
}
```

Para mais detalhes você pode ler na documentação sobre [salvar arquivos internamente e externamente](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html). Caso o dispositivo não tenha um local externo para salvar, o ideal é colocar uma condição no qual faz a verificação e salva o arquivo no local mais apropriado.

<sup>**Referências**</sup>

- [Saving Files](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

Comment: Entendi tua colocação. E se eu preferir salvar no armazenamento interno do device?

Comment: @fvmoraes fiz uma edição para melhor entendimento.

Answer (score 0):

É bem parecido com o sistema de arquivo no desktop. Usando o exemplo no [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html), use `File`:

```
File arquivo = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "arquivo.txt");
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(arquivo);
// escreva os dados aqui com output
```